# How important selecting android language while creating a new flutter project?

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, kotlin

When I create a flutter app with the android studio I see the options for selecting the specified language for both android and IOS. I do not know how to code with these languages so, I won't code with them. Therefore, I thought selecting one of them is not important for me, isn't it?

Comment: I suggest you to select the latest langage/version (like kotlin over java for android). So you won't have any trouble during your process. But as you said it's not important for you, until you have to inject some code in each native part.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on whether your app will be requiring access to Android or iOS Platform API. In most cases, there are plugins available at [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) for many of the APIs. But in case there is no plugin available for the API you need(rare cases), you will need to write platform specific code ([refer platform integration docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)) in the language you selected at beginning.

In most cases, selecting the language won't matter but it is recommended to use Kotlin for Android and Swift for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, it doesn't matter whether you choose Kotlin or Java for Android, Swift, or Objective-C for iOS because you won't need these languages in Flutter app development unless you want to add platform-specific features.

For example, suppose you are working on a Flutter app and you need to add a specific functionality called 'XYZ.' But Flutter doesn't support that functionality. Normally, this won't be the case because Flutter provides built-in libraries or plugins to solve most problems. However, let's assume that the specific functionality is not supported in Flutter but is available in Kotlin and Swift.

In such cases, you would implement that specific functionality using Java or Kotlin for the Android app and Swift or Objective-C for the iOS app.

So, in those particular scenarios, you should have knowledge of either Java or Kotlin, and either Swift or Objective-C.

If you are familiar with Java, choose Java. If you are familiar with Kotlin, choose Kotlin. And if you are not familiar with any of these languages, then for Android, select Kotlin, and for iOS, select Swift. Kotlin is a modern and recommended language for Android app development by Google, while Swift is recommended over Objective-C by Apple.

The language you choose will be used to generate the code for both the Android and iOS apps, which I will demonstrate at the end of this video

Answer (score 1):

Although for now you won't be coding in those native languages and most probably there is a good chance that all the platform related APIs you may need to integrate in future might be available in form of flutter plugin, but assuming at some point in future you might plan to scale your project further, then at some point you might have to deal with the native code for some specific feature.

So IMO it is a good practice to choose the programming language for native code wisely. I will recommend to always choose Kotlin for android because google follows Kotlin first approach along with that kotlin is a modern language and it has lots of advantages over java.

For ios Swift is recommended language due to similar reasons as kotlin.